# How to acces specific data in .data

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm pretty sure that it's possible, but I can't find how to acces some data in the .data section when they are declared like that (in nasm) :

```
msg: db 0xEA, 0xBA, 0x35, 0xB4, 0x88, 0x24, 0x14, 0x2C, 0xA1, 0x97, 0x5F, 0x1B, 0x56, 0xFA, 0xA3
```

For example, if I want to move the 4th to a register, how can I do that ?

Comment: I actually wanted to vote to close this but I don't see anything really close despite the elementary nature of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's extremely straightforward.  Here's the intel notation for it:

```
 mov al, [msg+3]
```

To address your followup question that is in the comments to this answer, you can iterate over the array like so, assuming a 16 bit model (for a 32 bit model, use ebx, etc.) (also note that I've added 0xFF to the end of your array.  There are lots of other ways to do this, this is just one):

```
     mov bx, msg
 next:
     mov al, [bx]
     cmp al, 0xff
     je  done
     call printAL
     inc bx
     jump next
 done:
     ret

 msg: db 0xEA, 0xBA, 0x35, 0xB4, 0x88, 0x24, 0x14, 0x2C, 0xA1, 0x97, 0x5F, 0x1B, 0x56, 0xFA, 0xA3, 0xFF
```

This code assumes that you have defined a function referenced as `printAL` to do something with `al` and that you have called this code from somewhere else (hence the `ret`).

Comment: Like I said I know that it's a very elementary question. Anyway, thank you for you response.

But I got another question related to the previous one: If I want to go through the array using a loop, how i'm supposed to do since:

 mov al, [msg+ 'register' ]

doesn't work ?

Is there any special register that as to be used in this case ?

Comment: I've added additional code to help you.  If the original answer solved your problem, you should accept the answer.  Additionally, rather than asking new questions in the comments, you really need to ask a new question.

Comment: @B.Wing  `mov al,[msg+eax]` works, so not sure what is not working for you. (maybe you are masochist trying to code for 16b real mode, then only some combinations are legal: https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/CH04/CH04-2.html#HEADING2-35  ... anyway, you can't "guess" what is legal in assembly, check Intel instruction guide for all the details what is valid and how each instruction works)

Comment: I'm really puzzled why so many schools seem to insist on teaching segmented memory.  Unless they're going to teach you to write a boot loader to then get you to protected or long mode, what's the point today?  Anyway, I suspect that's where the OP is coming from, @Ped7g

Comment: @DavidHoelzer maybe they want them to teach OS development.. oh wait, in OS you simply switch to protected mode as soon as you are ready. Hmm... maybe emu8086? I never seen it in action, but from the questions on SO I'm already disliking it, very sloppy assembler and the students still miss the debugging concept completely. So... must be some secret reason, can't see anything positive about it, especially for teaching purposes (once my friend did show me Watcom C + DOS/4GW, I wrote only very few bytes of 16b ASM .. usually at most 256B for 256B intro :D ).